# fprint cannot print concatenated string referenced by pointer returned from function

Tags: c, string, printf

I have the following program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXLEN 100

char *my_strcat(char *strp1,char *strp2) {

    char str[MAXLEN], *strp;
    strp = str;
    while (*strp1 != '\0') {
        *strp++ = *strp1++;
    }
    while (*strp2 != '\0') {
        *strp++ = *strp2++;
    }
    *strp = '\0';
    strp = str;
    return strp;
}

void test_strcat(void) {

char *strp1, *strp2, *strp3, str1[MAXLEN], str2[MAXLEN];
printf("Testing strcat! Give two strings:\n");
gets_s(str1, sizeof(str1));
gets_s(str2, sizeof(str2));
strp1 = str1;
strp2 = str2;
strp3 = my_strcat(strp1, strp2);
printf("Concatenated string: %s", strp3);

}


int main(void) {
test_strcat();
}
```

The function `char *mystrcat` is supposed to concatenate two strings, and I test it with 
`test_strcat`. The program runs without errors but instead of printing the concatenated string a smiley symbol is printed. I have gone through the program with debugging and it
appears that the result sent back by `my_strcat` is the correct string. However, when
going into the last line where `strp3` is supposed to be printed it appears red in the
debugging tool, implying that its value is about to change. After the printf call, `strp3`
no longer points to the concatenated string. Anyone knows what could be causing this error?

Comment: You are returning a local variable. You need to use `malloc` instead of the array. `char *strp = new char[MAXLEN];`

Comment: What is `str[MAXLEN]`? It appears to be uninitialized, never used, but it is what you return from your function... `strp = str; return strp;`

Comment: Try by `char *strp=(char *)malloc(MAXLEN*sizeof(char));` in `*my_strcat()` function.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why should a function not return a local array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16680092/why-should-a-function-not-return-a-local-array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the problem:

```
char str[MAXLEN], *strp;
strp = str;  // str is a local variable
...
return strp; // <<== WRONG!!!
```

Since `str` is a local variable that disappears as soon as you return, the value pointed to by `strp` becomes invalid the instance the caller gets the control back.

Use `malloc` instead of allocating memory in the automatic storage area (i.e. on the stack) will fix this problem:

```
char *str = malloc(strlen(strp1)+strlen(strp2)+1);
char *strp = str;
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch! I realized it would also be possible to add a third
argument to the function my_strcat that is a pointer to the memory where the new string is supposed to be stored. Which of these possibilities would be preferable in general?

Comment: @user3337301 In general, both these approaches are valid. The `malloc` approach is valid when you do not care where the string is stored, and you do not mind spending a few extra nanoseconds managing memory. An approach that takes an output buffer is inherently less safe, because it opens up possibilities for buffer overruns, but at the same time it lets you deal with stack and/or static memory, potentially saving on CPU time where it counts (this becomes relevant when you write device drivers or similar low-level code).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you 2 ways as following.

first,

```
char *my_strcat(char *strp1,char *strp2) {
    static char str[MAXLEN * 2]; /* from char str[MAXLEN] */
```

second,

```
char *my_strcat(char *strp1,char *strp2) {
    char *str = malloc(strlen(strp1) + strlen(strp2) + 1);
```

because in my_strcat function, you allocated the str as auto variable.
When my_strcat function is finish, str will be freed.